# What is the best option for a large slowly changing dimension lookup table

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, configuration, memory-optimized-tables

This question is an extension of a previously asked question [Index Strategy and Query optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231689/what-is-the-best-index-strategy-or-query-select-when-performing-a-search-lookup#231699), which further extends this question: [Search between IP string addresses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230787/unable-to-search-between-ipv6-range-when-converting-string-ip-address-to-varbina)

I implemented the two new indexes that Ypercube recommended. While the query for the InsideIp lookup completed much faster (1.5 **minutes** versus 9 minutes), the OutsideIp lookup is still running after 1.5 **hours**. I will let the query run over the weekend to see if it even completes. Note: the InsideIp list contains 3 DISTINCT IPs while the OutsideIp list contains approximately 60K DISTINCT IPs.

I understand the server may be constrained memory-wise and probably needs more memory and potententially a combination of more CPUs and disk(s) (for multiple database files that allow for LUN/stream optimization).

Before I travel down that path, I am thinking three alternative approaches.

1. Change the clustered index as previously mentioned (ProtocolKey, NetworkStartIpHex, NetworkEndIpHex, RowKey)
2. Place the lookup columns (ProtocolKey, NetworkStartIpHex, NetworkEndIpHex, RowKey) in an in-memory (OLTP) table.
3. Partition the table. But, not sure how to effectively partition over a VARBINARY(16) column. I know VARBINARY(MAX) is explicitly ruled out by Microsoft, but is VARBINARY(16) ruled out as well?

Can anyone provide some insights as to which might be better?

Comment: Have you tried a clustered column store index at all?

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Initially I did not even consider it due to limitations that exclude INCLUDE and ALTER statements. Would you say column store index is better? If yes, can you provide some insights?